# How to use ValueListenableProvider

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to understand how to use [ValueListenableProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ValueListenableProvider/ValueListenableProvider.value.html) but I'm quite confused, let's follow the example on the linked page:

```dart
ValueListenable<int> foo;

ValueListenableProvider<int>.value(
  valueListenable: foo,
  child: Container(),
);
```

Ok, this provides foo to all child widgets, but how do I recover it?
 For example, in ChangeNotifierProvider I use the type to get my reference back e.g. `Provider.of<SomeType>(context)`. What would be SomeType here? int?

Comment: could you solve your problem?

Comment: Long time since I used flutter, so I don't remember the exact solution. But I remember that doing something similar of what Rémi suggested actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValueListenableProvider` exposes `ValueListenable.value`.

As such to read from a `ValueListenableProvider<int>`, you need to use `Provider.of<int>(context)`

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example on how to do this?  

In the OP what is the easiest way of initializing a value for foo (my first reaction was to do `ValueListenable<int> foo = 42;`

Should I do something similar to [this](https://github.com/2d-inc/developer_quest/blob/master/lib/src/shared_state/game/company.dart#L76)?

Comment: It's deprecated now. What's the alternate way?